# Search and edit function in a account manager does not work

Tags: c, file, search

Hello i wrote a account manager and in a function that should edit the accounts it always fails and i do not get it why it fails

here is the code:

```
int edit(void)
{
   FILE *file;
   char input[max];
   char search[max];
   char typ[max];
   char output[max+30];
   int outputzahl;
   char u;
   int f;
   int ff;

   printf("Bitte geben sie den Accounttyp ein von welchen account sie etwas veraendern wollen: ");
   if(!fgets(typ, sizeof typ, stdin))
   {
       printf("Einlesefehler\n");
       return 1;
   }
   NL(typ);

   printf("Bitte geben sie nun die Email vom Account ein: ");
   if(!fgets(search, sizeof search, stdin))
   {
                    printf("Outputfehler#11\n");
                    return 1;
    }
    NL(search);
               
   while(fgets(input, sizeof input, file) == 0)
   {
       if(strcmp(search, input) == 0)
       {
           fseek(file, -strlen(search), SEEK_CUR);
           fseek(file, -strlen(typ), SEEK_CUR);
           f = ftell(file);

           printf("t. Typ Ver\x84ndern\n");
           printf("e. Email ver\x84ndern\n");
           printf("p. Passwort ver\x84ndern\n");
           printf("d. Tag ver\x84ndern\n");
           printf("m. Monat ver\x84ndern\n");
           printf("j. Jahr ver\x84ndern\n");
           printf("n. notiz ver\x84ndern\n");

           u = getchar();
           while(u != EOF &&  getchar() != EOF);

           if (u == 't')
           {
               fseek(file, f, SEEK_SET);
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
               printf("%s ist der Jetziger typ\n", output);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               fgets(output, sizeof output, stdin);
               fprintf(file, "%s", output);
           }

           if(u == 'e')
           {
               fseek(file, f, SEEK_SET);
               fgets(output, sizeof output, file);
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
               printf("%s ist die Jetzige email\n", output);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               fgets(output, sizeof output, stdin);
               fprintf(file, "%s", output);
           }

           if(u == 'p')
           {
               fseek(file, f, SEEK_SET);
               for(int h = 0; h < 2; h++)
               {
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
               }
               printf("%s ist das Jetzige Passwort\n", output);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               fgets(output, sizeof output, stdin);
               fprintf(file, "%s", output);
           }

           if(u == 'd')
           {
               fseek(file, f, SEEK_SET);

               for(int h = 0; h < 3; h++)
                {
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                }

               ff = atoi(fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
               printf("%i ist der Jetzige Tag\n", ff);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               scanf("%i", &outputzahl);
               fprintf(file, "%i", outputzahl);
           }

           if(u == 'm')
           {
               fseek(file, f, SEEK_SET);

               for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++)
               {
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
               }

               ff = atoi(fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
               printf("%i ist der Jetzige Monat\n", ff);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               scanf("%i", &outputzahl);
               fprintf(file, "%i", outputzahl);
           }

           if(u == 'j')
           {
               fseek(file, f, SEEK_SET);

               for(int h = 0; h < 5; h++)
               {
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
               }

               ff = atoi(fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
               printf("%i ist das Jetzige Jahr\n", ff);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               scanf("%i", &outputzahl);
               fprintf(file, "%i", outputzahl);
           }

           if(u == 'n')
           {
               fseek(file, sizeof output, SEEK_SET);

               for(int h = 0; h < 6; h++)
               {
               if(!fgets(output, sizeof output, file));
                {
                    printf("Fehler vom lesen der datei\n");
                    return 1;
                }
               }

               printf("%s ist die Jetzige Notiz\n", output);
               printf("Neuer input: ");
               fgets(output, sizeof output, file);
               fprintf(file, "%s", output);
           }
           
       }
   }
}
```

when i try to search a entry with the typ:Google  email:test@gmail.com  password: test  day: 1 month: 2   year:2022   notitz: test

it comes a segmention fault or when it succes it dont print the account

Comment: What does NL function do ? 
Have you tried to to use valgrind as follow: valgrind --leak-check=full ./example

Comment: So debug it. Run your program in a debugger. At a minimum it will give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. That is the *minimum* debug info you should post in the question. Can also use the debugger to step thru the code and watch it as it runs. If you need further help here please follow the Stack Overflow requirements and post complete code as a [mre].

Comment: `atoi(fgets(output, sizeof output, file))` This looks suspicious. Should always check the return value of `fgets` before using it. If it is `NULL` it would not be surprising for `atoi` to seg fault. But again, a debugger will instantly confirm whether that is the case or not.

Comment: `fseek(file, -strlen(search), SEEK_CUR);` strlen returns an unsigned value, you cannot make it negative without first converting it to a signed type.

Comment: FYI, `char u;` should be `int u;`

Comment: You haven't opened the `file`. So you are also passing an uninitialised pointer to `fgets()`. Doesn't the compiler warn you about that?

Comment: `while(fgets(input, sizeof input, file) == 0)` That looks wrong. Should be `!=`

Comment: the NL function removes the \n UnDesSix

Comment: kaylum when i try to run the gdb debugger in a layout its is so buggy that i cant use it